# Hard coding an expiry date for a web app (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

Say you want to upload a "beta" version, and you have trust issues.
How would you go about adding an expiry date?

I thought about hard coding an expiry date - but then anyone could decompile/recompile the .NET dlls.

Then I thought maybe I should make the app iterate over its own files and delete them. But then, the IIS worker will stop after deleting an important dll, and we won't be able to delete the others. Not to mention the fact that we'll need to set write permissions on all folders including BIN.

Well... Any ideas?

Comment: By trust issues, you mean you can't host a windows service?

Comment: I mean that we need to temporarily host in someone's server, someone we don't completely trust.

Comment: if you dont trust em dont do it, simple, never put yourself in a place where youre handing out something important to someone you dont trust, if they are that determined to break your protection and get hold of the stuff they will.

Comment: I agree also - but in the real world, some situations are more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the date as some meaningful input variable deep inside your code, like using "ticks over threshold" to calculate some planned reduction in scalability, all set at different time thresholds, introducing delays or something. If you put these in several places and mark with comments .cs, these would be easy for you to remove when needed, but too expensive to root out from a dll.

Comment: I actually like that idea very much. This is one step in the way for a complete solution...

Answer (score 1):

Add hardcoded date check somewhere, and [obfuscate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrsecurity/archive/2005/05/26/422440.aspx) your application.

**Update:**

I wouldn't say that would be easy to find a date check in obfuscated assembly, especially if you use some of commercial tools. Of course this can't be 100% secure, I don't have any experience debugging / cracking obfuscated assemblies but spend some time googling for commercial obfuscators and what they can do.

Besides from that you could use the fact that your application runs connected to internet, you can check for some outside resource, of course that could easily be sniffed, but you could code some essential part of your application is some script put that script encrypted on some other server. Then your application should download, decrypt and execute that script, so if you remove it from remote server it would be very hard to reproduce that functionality. There is a possibility that 3rd party downloads that script and serve it when becomes unavailable, be aware of that. Maybe you can use [Rosyln](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113169/C-As-A-Scripting-Language-In-Your-NET-Applications) and use your c# code instead of that script.

I didn't do anything similar, maybe there are some more problems, it's just something that crossed my mind so if you want to go this way do your research please :)

Comment: That wouldn't be enough for me, as date checks could easily be found. But maybe I'll combine that with deleting the most key files I can. I'm gonna sleep on that, and maybe come out with a more complete solution.